# .prev() not acting according to jQuery api documentation?

Tags: jquery

Just out of general curiosity I would like to know why one markup works opposed to the other in relation to `.prev`

According to the api, using `.prev` you can manipulate the predecessor of the element.

**jQuery:** *Here is just a snippet, full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/4/).*

```
    jQuery('.add').click(function (e) {

        var copy = jQuery('#static-copy-sample .static-sublayers > #log1').clone();

        copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev().find('.static-sublayers'));

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
     <div class="static-sublayers">
         <div id="log1">elf <span class="will">1</span> </div>
     </div>

     <a class="add" href="#">Add</a>
```

Basically the `a` above is the element `el` and I `appendTo` the `.prev()` block, the only way I get it to work is by wrapping the `.static-sublayers` with a div?

From my understanding of the api, the `.prev` gets the previous element, so I am not sure why I have to wrap it?

This is such a novice question, but again I ask this out of pure curiousity in hopes to get better at jQuery and specifically understanding `.prev()` a little better and general ticky tack things like this.

Again the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/4/) shows the code in much more depth and you can understand me better, I have the working HTML commented out.

**EDIT:**
As soon as I posted this I messed with the fiddle, and found my answer. I tried to thoroughly test everything before posting I did this before asking `copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev('.static-sublayers'));` then realized I need to leave `.prev` empty like `.prev()`... So if the target is nested then `.find()` is a good solution, but if the markup is simple and literally the previous element not nested at all then `copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev());` is the solution.

Comment: You use `el` here but it isn't defined anywhere `copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev().find('.static-sublayers'));`

Comment: Yeah I found using `copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev());` worked... the .find is going to come in handy though in the live code, turns out if the target is nested then the above logic is needed. but if its straightforward unlike the live code, then this `copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev());` is suitable.

Comment: The previous element IS `".static-sublayers"`, therefore `.find()` doesn't find anything because `.find()` only looks at descendants, not the current element. `.find()` isn't needed.

Comment: @Jbird Its defined in the fiddle, I just wanted to quickly put a snippet here.. sorry if its misleading but I didnt want to add a whole lot of code...

Comment: Far better to have all of the code here and no fiddle than only a little code here that doesn't make sense and then the best fiddle on the net linked.

Comment: ok, I always thought a fiddle was the best way to go, I didnt want an extra long answer, ill keep that in mind for next time...

Comment: Is this what you're wanting to do? [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/7/) Remember, you'll need to update the id incrementally as well. I added that to the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.prev().find('.static-sublayers')` which will search for `.static-sublayers` in div with class `static-sublayers`. Try using this:

```
copy.appendTo(jQuery(el).prev());
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah such a simple mistake, I literally found that out right after asking.. but to be fair this did help me understand how `.prev()` works a little better and using `.find` is good if the target is nested within the previous block.